# How to Specify an IP Address for TcpClient to use

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcpclient

During development, we usually use localhost as the hostname, like the following

```
 Dim serverListener As New TcpClient("localhost", 8585)
```

I want the user to be able to enter their IP address via a TextBox instead, like

```
Dim serverListener As New TcpClient(textbox1.text, 8585)
```

However, this is not working for me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/local-ip/) will help?

You can also use [IPAdress.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) to check if its a valid adress

Answer (score 1):

The form of the [`TcpClient` constructor that accepts a `string` and an `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56.aspx) parameter expects a hostname and a port, not an IP address.

You might want to use the [`TcpClient` constructor that takes an `IPEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx) parameter instread. There is more information on the [`IPEndPoint` class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx), but in short it represents an IP address and a port number.